# Can I use .NET core with only F# or will I need to learn C# too?

Tags: c#, .net, f#, .net-core

F# has recently caught my eye as something I'd like to learn more about, but I have never used the .NET platform and know very little about it. If I want to write a small website in .NET core can I do that with only F# or will I need to expand my learnings to include C#?

Comment: The BCL is object-oriented and implemented in C# but you don't need to know C# to use it.

Comment: Don't forget [the Stack Overflow F# Chat Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51909/f)

Comment: If you do anything .NET related, you'll inevitably come across C# every now and again, so it's probably helpful not to be entirely oblivious to it. As a rule of thumb, I'd say it's a good idea to know C# well enough to understand why you'd rather use F#.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can definitely use .NET Core with pure F#. There is no C# knowledge required, though it can be beneficial to familiarize yourself with it enough to understand usage and library documentation.

The official Getting Started with F# guide has a [section on using .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/get-started/get-started-command-line) with "just F#", which you can use as a starting point.

As for writing a website, I highly recommend looking at the [SAFE Stack](https://safe-stack.github.io/) intro, docs, and samples. It shows how you can use only F# for full stack web development, all using .NET Core.

Answer (score 7):

This depends on your learning and working style.

Technically, F# does not need any support from C#. You can write complete programs of any kind whatsoever without ever touching C#.

However, a lot of F# resources online are geared towards migrating from C# to F#, and as a result are phrased in terms of the differences between the two. Something like "*you've been doing this thing in C# before, but here's how it can be done way better in F#*".

Additionally, a lot of .NET libraries are written in C#. The binaries are, of course, completely compatible with F#, so you don't need to do any sort of special tricks to use C#-written libraries. However, if you ever want to look at the source code, that's where C# knowledge would come in handy.

To be fair, there is quite a large number of F#-exclusive libraries out there, but the majority of .NET libraries are still in C#. So chances are, you will end up using some of them. Whether you would actually want to look at their source - that depends on your style.

Answer (score 1):

There are some libraries that I could never get working nicely in F#, so I tend to have some C# projects built into my solution to handle things that I just could not find an elegant way of doing in F# - like using the high level "Nest" Elasticsearch driver. It is designed to give you very elegant code in C# but I found it was the exact opposite in F#, sort of defeating the point of using a high level driver.

C# is nothing to fear though, it is readable and intuitive for the most part. I came into F# with no knowledge of .NET and have learned what I've needed as I've gone along without any troubles.